# How can i clean urdu data corpus Python without nltk

Tags: python-2.7, nlp, urdu

I have a corpus of more that 10000 words in urdu. Now what i want is to clean my data. There appear a special uni coded data in my text like "!؟ـ،" whenever i use regular expressions it gives me error that your data is not in encoded form. 
Kindly provide me some help to clean my data. 
Thank you

Here is my sample data:

> ظہیر
>
> احمد
>
> ماہرہ
>
> خان
>
> کی،
>
> تصاویر،
>
> نے
>
> دائیں
>
> اور
>
> بائیں
>
> والوں
>
> کو
>
> آسمانوں
>
> پر
>
> پہنچایا
>
> ،ہوا
>
> ہے۔
>
> دائیں؟
>
> والے

Comment: I recommend providing a sample of the data your dealing with

Comment: I have added my sample data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used your sample to find all words with `ہ` or `ر`

Notice that I had to tell python that I am dealing with utf-8 data by using u in front of the regex string as well as the data string

```
import re
data = u"""
ظہیر

احمد

ماہرہ

خان

.....
"""
result = re.findall(u'[^\s\n]+[ہر][^\s\n]+',data,re.MULTILINE)
print(result)
```

The output was

```
['ظہیر', 'ماہرہ', 'تصاویر،', 'پہنچایا', '،ہوا']
```

another example, removes all none alphabets except whitespace and makes sure only one whitespace separates the words

```
result = re.sub(' +',' ',re.sub(u'[\W\s]',' ',data))
print(result)
```

the output is

```
 ظہیر احمد ماہرہ خان کی تصاویر نے دائیں اور بائیں والوں کو آسمانوں پر پہنچایا ہوا ہے دائیں والے
```

you can also use word tokanizer,

```
import nltk
result = nltk.tokenize.wordpunct_tokenize(data)
print(result)
```

the output will be

```
['ظہیر', 'احمد', 'ماہرہ'
 , 'خان', 'کی', '،', 'تصاویر'
 , '،', 'نے', 'دائیں', 'اور', 'بائیں', 'والوں'
 , 'کو', 'آسمانوں', 'پر', 'پہنچایا'
 , '،', 'ہوا', 'ہے', '۔', 'دائیں', '؟', 'والے']
```

Edit ... for Python 2.7 you have to specify the encoding at the beginning of the code file as well as telling `re` that the regex is 'unicode' using `re.UNICODE`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
import re

data = u"""ظہیر

احمد

ماہرہ

خان

کی،

.....

"""


result = re.sub(ur'\s+',u' ',re.sub(ur'[\W\s]',ur' ',data,re.UNICODE),re.UNICODE)
print(result)
```

also note the use of `ur''` to specify the string is a unicode regex string

Comment: I used this code 
'import codecs
'import re
file1 = codecs.open("foo1.txt", "r",encoding="utf-8")
for line in file1:
    result = re.sub(' +',' ',re.sub(u'[\W\s\d]',' ',line))
    print (result)`

But it still didn't work

Comment: which version of python do you use and what error did you get.

Comment: its python27. 
i didn't get any error result was nothing. means empty

Comment: Ane when i tried to compile your code its gives me error: 
** File "fa.py", line 10
    ظہیر
        ^
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xd8' in file fa.py on line 11, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details**

Comment: yes my code works on python3.5/3.6 I'll check on python2.7 and let you know

Comment: it's still giving me same error i dont know where i am doing wrong

Comment: try checking the encoding of the file you use. I use sublime text3, I changed the file encoding to UTF-8 from the File-> save with encoding->UTF-8

Comment: great you solved my problem and save my life 
Thank you.